# Is there any shortcut to iterate through Excel's worksheet tabs?

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts

Is there any keyboard shortcut to iterate through Excel's worksheet tabs more easily?

Maybe something that would allow me to see all the tabs together and select one of them to switch to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right click on any bottom corner left arrow keys, you will see list of all sheets and select the required sheet on the workbook.

Refer my screenshot:-

[image]

Comment: This is great! Isn't there any way to do this without using mouse?

Comment: there could be a very visible disclaimer that ***this is not keyboard***

Comment: Does not answer the question

Comment: It does answer the second part of the question: "Maybe something that would allow me to see all the tabs together and select one of them to switch to it."

Answer (score 63):

**Windows:**

- Switch between worksheets: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>PgDn</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>PgUp</kbd>
- Switch between workbooks: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>

On Logitech Mx Keys Mini, you can shift tabs using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>UP</kbd>/<kbd>DOWN</kbd> arrows.

**macOS:**

- Switch between worksheets:
  <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd> or <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd>, or
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⇞</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⇟</kbd> on a keyboard with numpad
- Switch between workbooks: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>

Comment: how, if, can these be remapped?

Comment: Not sure as I don't have Office (anymore). Maybe you can ask a new question about that?

Comment: I've confirmed that either control or command (⌘) work for these shortcuts on macOS.

Comment: To be super pedantic, Fn+Ctrl+<arrow> also works on a large keyboard.

Answer (score 9):

For mac OSX:
To switch between tabs in a worksheet: <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>up</kbd>/<kbd>down</kbd>!

Comment: slhck writes it's `Ctrl` instead of `Cmd` -- could you specify which version of Excel your answer refers to? Maybe it changed?

Comment: @DanielBeck: Nothing's changed, in the Windows version at least. My guess is Matt is using a laptop keyboard with a typically weird layout that requires you to press Fn to change the behaviour of other keys. slhck's answer is sufficient IMO.

Comment: @Karan There's no `Command` key on Windows computers (the equivalent `Windows` key not being used for program keyboard shortcuts), and every Mac has both `Command` and `Control` keys. The `Fn` is needed to make `Arrow` keys into `Home/End/PgUp/PgDn` as shown in slhck's answer.

Comment: @DanielBeck: Yes, I know Fn is used to change the behaviour of other keys, as I already said above. Perhaps in this case Ctrl and Command can be used interchangeably, and both `Fn + Ctrl + Up/Down` and `Fn + Command + Up/Down` do the same thing on a Mac keyboard?

Comment: They are interchangeable. (Both work.) Tested on OS X 10.9.2 "Mavericks" with Excel 2011 v 14.3.9

Comment: Worst shortcut ever. Might as well just use the mouse

Comment: Tip: if you use a trackpad, download the free BetterTouchTool app and map them to "TipTapLeft" and "TipTapRight"

Comment: @JaydenLawson I think ctrl-alt-delete is just as bad or worse, and also vastly more widespread. As shick points out you can use fn-ctrl-up/down which has the advantage of fn and ctrl being together at the bottom far-left of keyboard and so easy to press with one hand without looking. The up/down arrows are also on the same line (at the bottom of keyboard) and are easy for me to find without looking.

Comment: what i was looking for

Comment: @DanielBeck Really late to the party here, but you can use either ctrl OR command along with fn and the up/down arrows. They both work.

Answer (score 4):

To cycle between sheets press Option + (Left or Right Arrow)

Comment: OS/X 2022: *THIS* is the right answer

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

1. Use <kbd>Alt+F11</kbd> to add a new module
2. Paste

   ```
   Sub ShowAllSheets()
       Application.CommandBars("Workbook tabs").ShowPopup
   End Sub
   ```
3. Close the window and use <kbd>Alt+F8</kbd> to open the macro running window
4. Click on `ShowAllSheets` and options on the side
5. Add shortcut.